# Collecting votes across multiple sites

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drupal, vote

I am looking for a solution that allows people to submit their vote to the main site via a voting system or banner.

At the moment, I am aware of one solution that works with drigg and drupal, but it requires url redirect or mod_rewite that is not currently available on the clients server.

Is anyone aware of a solution that would allow people to record their vote from a banner sitting on a separate site, while maintaining a single website that collects all the data from anonymous users? Alternatively, what approach might one take to implement this solution. Is it posible to use drigg without mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

As Artefacto said, there are limitations with Ajax when it comes to cross-site requests, but what you could do is display the banner within an iframe on the external site, that way the iframe can get the src that sits on your home server, which you have complete access to. This way you'll be able to record the votes and still maintain complete control.

Google does a similar thing with adsense.

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a great solution. Thanks.

Comment: just checked and the banners are likely to be on a cdn so this is probably not an option, although I do think it is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the votes are submitted to another site, the only problem is that you may go into cross-site requests limitations when using Ajax.

It should work fine, however, if you use a normal html form whose action is another site (namely the main site that collects the votes).

Answer (score 0):

using the services module might also be a solution. I believe there is a json listener and it should be possible to make web services calls to the other server using the services module.